# Calculate & subtract percentage in C#

Tags: c#, percentage

Well I know this would be a very easy question ,but i am poor at this concept of Maths.
I know what my final answer should be ,but this answer should come after I subtract some specific percentage from another amount. I want to know what that another amount should be.

Making it a bit simpler : 
this is my equation : x - 12% of x should result in 250$. I need to find x.
( Please know if I add 12% to 250 , it will be wrong as 12% of 250 would be different from 12% of what that another amount would be ).

Thank you friends.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic math

Answer (score 2):

This is simply algebra (not necessarily even relevant to C#).

Your equation is:

[image: x - 0.12*x = 250]

Solve for [image: x]:

[image: 0.88*x = 250]

[image: x = 250/0.88]

Therefore this can be calculated in C#:

```
double x = 250/0.88;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

which outputs `284.090909090909`